# Text layer under image HTML/CSS

Tags: html, image, hover, layer

I have a picture that disappears on hover. How can I place text below/behind the image? So that when the picture disappears people will be able to see the text.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use absolute positioning and the CSS `z-index` property:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;

  z-index: 2;
}

img:hover {
  z-index: 0;
}

div {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Semi-functional demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qsmzf/3/**

Answer (score 2):

using z-index should do it

```
img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:1;
}
```

That should put the image on top of the text and then when you hover it should show the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the image's CSS to have `position: absolute;` then you can set the `z-index` property to overlay the text. You may have to put the image in a container with `position: relative;` as the absolute positioning may move the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NPExr/

Comment: Try making this with only CSS. Your image will flash quite violently ;)